# How to pass dynamic parameter to setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to pass a parameter to `setInterval` function like below

```
load(value) {
        let checkedValue = value;;
        let checkExist = setInterval(function (checkedValue ) {
            if ((document.getElementsByClassName("switch")).length > 0) {
                ($(".switch") as any).kendoSwitch({
                    checked: checkedValue 
                }).data("kendoSwitch");               
             clearInterval(checkExist); 
            }            
        }, 100)        
    }
```

`CheckedValue` is not accessible here, what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` passes all extraneous parameters to the callback function:

```
   let checkExist = setInterval(function (checkedValue) {
        if ((document.getElementsByClassName("switch")).length > 0) {
            ($(".switch") as any).kendoSwitch({
                checked: checkedValue 
            }).data("kendoSwitch");               
         clearInterval(checkExist); 
        }            
    }, 100, checkedValue); // Note checkedValue is passed as the final parameter
```

However, you can rely on closures to make this work

```
  load(value) {
    let checkExist = setInterval(function () {
        if ((document.getElementsByClassName("switch")).length > 0) {
            ($(".switch") as any).kendoSwitch({
                checked: value
            }).data("kendoSwitch");               
         clearInterval(checkExist); 
        }            
    }, 100)        
  }
```